# Understanding change of variables in double integrals

Tags: change-of-variable

In this [libre text chapter](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Book%3A_Calculus_(OpenStax)/15%3A_Multiple_Integration/15.7%3A_Change_of_Variables_in_Multiple_Integrals), in example 15.7.1B, the author illustrates the change of variables using the following example:

[image]

The statement near it is written:

For the vertical length  $A:u=0,0≤v≤1$  transforms to  $x=−v^2,y=0$  so this is the horizontal length $A′ $ that joins  $(−1,0)$  and $ (0,0)$

I find it confusing that regardless of whatever function of $x$ could have been on $v$, it seems that all of them would only have a straight line of $A'$ like suppose it was $x=-v^3$, that'd also denote the same line

If I understood correctly, we derive $A'$ from $A$ by feeding constraints of $A$ into the dependencies of the new variables on the old. Under that idea, does the kind of function $x$ is on the old coordinates not matter in sketching the region(only the bounds does)?

Comment: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/changeofvariables.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the mapping
\begin{align*}
x&=u^2-v^2\tag{1}\\
y&=uv\tag{2}
\end{align*}
from the $u,v$-plane in the $x,y$-plane is also given in (2) by $y=uv$. This means whenever we set $\color{blue}{u=0}$, we have $y=0$ *regardless* of the setting of $v$.

- Nevertheless the mapping to *[parabolic coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_coordinates)* given by (1) and (2) is often used since it is a one-to-one mapping with very nice geometrical properties:

  - The curves $x = \mathrm{constant}$ give rise in the $u,v$-plane to the rectangular hyperbolas $u^2-v^2=\mathrm{constant}$. They have asymptotes which are $u=v$ and $u=-v$. The lines $y = \mathrm{constant}$ also correspond to a family of rectangular hyperbolas. Here the asymptotes are the coordinate axes. The hyperbolas of each family cut those of the other family at right angles.
  - The lines parallel to the axes in the $u,v$-plane correspond to two families of parabolas in the $x,y$-plane. The parabolas $y^2=c^2(c^2-x)$ correspond to the lines $u=c$ and the parabolas $y^2=k^2(k^2+x)$ correspond to the lines $v=k$. All these parabolas have the origin as focus and the $x$-axis as axis. They form a famliy of confocal  and coaxial parabolas.

This explanation can be found for instance in the classic *[Introduction to Calculues and Analysis II](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540665692)* by R. Courant and F. John.

I also like the following application of this kind of bijective mapping given by the authors. In the following we denote in OP's example the region bounded by the line segments $A,B$ and $C$ with $R$ and the region bounded by the curve segments $A^{\prime}, B^{\prime}$ and $C^{\prime}$ with $R^{\prime}$.

- One-one transformations have an important interpretation and application in the representation of *deformations* or *motions of continuously
  distributed substances*, such as fluids. If we think of such a substance as spread out at a given time over a region $R$ and then deformed by a motion, the substance originally spread over $R$ will in general cover a region $R^{\prime}$ different from $R$. Each particle of the substance can be distinguished at the beginning of the motion by its coordinates $(u,v)$ in $R$ and at the end of the motion by its coordinates $(x,y)$ in $R^{\prime}$. The $1$-$1$ character of the transformation obtained by bringing $(u,v)$ into correspondence with $(x,y)$ is simply the mathematical expression of the physically obvious fact that separate particles remain separate.

Comment: This answer was very intuitive for me but there is one particular point which is bothering me, you have describe one to one transformations as deformations of continously distributed substances but there are some transformations which the shape of the region is boundary. For example consider the boundary: $x^2 +y^2 = 1$ , now if we convert this to polar $ r^2 =1$ , that describes the exact same shape, so I think there are two types of transformations 1. which deforms the area enclosed boundary 2. one which doesn't.

Comment: Are there names for this kind of transformations? A discussion about this point in the answer would be a great addition to this answer @Markus Scheuer

Comment: @Buraian: The application with fluids and motion was just an important physical example. You're right course,  the boundaries need not always be changed when considering transformations as in your example when considering the unit disc with center $(0,0)$ and going from rectangular coordinates to polar coordinates.

Comment: @Buraian: These coordinates are called *parabolic*. I've added a corresponding hint. The referred Wiki page directs you also to *curvilinear coordinates* and *orthogonal coordinate systems* which might be interesting.

Comment: @Buraian: Many thanks for accepting my answer and granting the bounty! :-)

Answer (score 1):

1. When you transform a **range** to another **range** via a transformation, the relation between old and new variables are fixed by that transformation.
2. When you transform a **range** to another **range** via a transformation, the only thing you need is to find the boundary of new range.
3. When you transform a **range** to another **range** via a transformation, it has not yet involve any functions.

Let us see a function $f(v,u)$ defined on a domain $D$, your ***only*** task is to transform the domain of the function $f(v,u)$ to a **new** function $\tilde f(x,y)$ on a **new** domain $\tilde D$. You do not need to know the exact form of the function, only thing you need is to find the boundary of $\tilde D$, based on knowing the boundary of $D$ and the transformation.

Comment: "  You do not need to know the exact form of the function, only thing you need is to find the boundary of D~," why??